# .gitignore not ignoring subdirectory, tried it all

Tags: git

I have tried putting all kinds of crazyness into the gitignore file,
I would like to ignore all files in the public/dist folder

public/dist/
public/
*/public/dist/
**/public/dist

and all other kinda of variations.

this is what I see when I run git status, I want to ignore the bundle.js
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After you've added the new `.gitignore` to your working index, don't forget to remove any files that you don't want to track via `git rm --cached`.  In your case, you'd want to use `git rm --cached public/dist/bundle.js` to stop tracking that file.

Comment: ah finally! after spending 2 hours trying to figure out why I couldn't remove my tracked files, finally got it! thank you!

Comment: Thanks, finally!